# Using PEAR::Soap on PHP v5.3

Tags: php, soap, pear

I have had to create a web service in PHP for a system I am busy on. I have got it to work using PEAR::Soap on PHP 5.3, but on the logs it gets spammed with errors and notices. I have tried going through the code and fixing the errors, but each time I fix one set of errors, another set appear.

Is there a version which will run without errors? Or an alternative that is just as easy to use?

Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php
I'd worked with PHP's SoapServer and Client. It works perfectly.
Also you can try Zend_Soap. (Built on PHP's Soap)

Comment: I have finally gotten around to redoing the system using Zend Framework and therefore using Zend_Soap. Loving ZF

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use the one from PEAR -- PHP has had SOAP client and server classes built in since v5.0.1

See http://uk.php.net/soapclient and http://uk.php.net/soapserver

Hope that helps.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the PHP Soap Server doesn't automatically generate the WSDL? Or am I mistaken?